# Setting font type globally in a multipart document

Tags: fonts

I have a master document with multiple child documents called by `\input` commands. I would like to set the palatino font globally for the main document and all of the child documents. Is it possible to add a command to accomplish this on the master document?

A cut down version of the main document:

```
%Novel template 5.06in x 7.81in, facing pages
% Begin document
\documentclass[11pt,english,british,twoside,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{novel}% novel.sty

%Frontmatter

\begin{document}

...

\mainmatter

%The Chapters
\input{./child_docs/child_docs.tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `\usepackage{palatino}` in the preamble makes it? Or did I miss something?

Comment: Thanks - yes I had written that into the novel.sty but was not sure if the font was changed in all of the child documents. But the pdf printout seem to use the same font (presumably palatino) throughout.

Comment: `\input file.tex` is *just like* adding the contents of `file.tex` into your document. So if the package would affect the text if you typed it in there instead, it will affect the text if you input it there. (Exception: there are some packages which can change this a bit but this would only happen if you deliberately did stuff to make it happen. And it is not that straightforward to set stuff up that way.)

Comment: @Clément Do you want to write an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Summarising the discussion

Adding

```
\usepackage{palatino}
```

to the main file before `\begin{document}` will effect this.  Material in `file.tex` include via `\input file.tex` in standard set-ups behaves exactly as if were entered in the main file.